# tikzcd/tikz matrices: remove space in empty node to connect wires

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I'd like to create nodes in `tikz` with exactly zero space around it, notably to connect stuff to it in tikz matrices/`tikz-cd`. If I force the anchor to be centered it works, but I'd prefer to directly find a style that removes space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  myNone/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}
}
% Ideally this should work:
\begin{tikzcd}
  |[myNone]| \rar[-] & |[myNone]| \rar[-] & |[myNone]|
\end{tikzcd}

Otherwise this work, but not optimal:
\begin{tikzcd}
  |[myNone]| \rar[-,start anchor=center,end anchor=center] & |[myNone]| \rar[-,start anchor=center,end anchor=center] & |[myNone]|
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution: just use the `shape=coordinate` to change the shape from rectangle to coordinate. Note however that this node can't have any width/height/outer space... so it can't be used to also add some spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  myNone/.style={shape=coordinate}
}
% Ideally this should work:
\begin{tikzcd}
  |[myNone]| \rar[-] & |[myNone]| \rar[-] & |[myNone]|
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzset{
  myNone/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}
        }

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
|[myNone]| \ar[rr] &   & |[myNone]|
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's a bit cheating, here you just create a single path. In my goal I need to connect multiple paths together which can't be replaced by a single arrow.

Comment: @tobiasBora, context of the your problem is not clear. Why you like to draw a arrow from point a to point b in two connected segments when you can draw it simple in one? That someone can help you, you must add more context to your problem.  Your wish, how you like to draw arrow in `tikzcd`,  cannot become true.